# VsCode auto import with TS aliases from node_modules

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, alias, tsconfig, auto-import

I have an Angular app with `@atmlib` package. `tsconfig`'s relevant settings are as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@share/*": ["src/app/share/*"],
            "@proto/*": ["node_modules/@atmlib/proto/grpc-web/web/*"],
        }
    }
}
```

The `@proto` alias works fine, but VsCode's autocomplete doesn't use it:
[image]

Though all the other aliases both work fine and auto importable:
[image]

The question is how to make auto import work with aliased package from `node_modules`?

Answer (score -1):

I have exactly the same issue ‍♂️

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "checkJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "theme/*": [
        "./src/web/theme/*",
        "./node_modules/my-library/my-module-a/web/theme/*",
        "./node_modules/my-library/my-module-b/web/theme/*",
        "./node_modules/my-library/my-module-c/web/theme/*",
      ],
      "web/*": [
        "./src/web/*",
        "./node_modules/my-library/my-module-a/web/*",
        "./node_modules/my-library/my-module-b/web/*",
        "./node_modules/my-library/my-module-c/web/*",
      ],
      "server/*": ["./node_modules/my-library/src/server/*"],
      "config/*": [
        "./src/config/*",
        "./node_modules/my-library/my-module-a/config/*",
        "./node_modules/my-library/my-module-b/config/*",
        "./node_modules/my-library/my-module-c/config/*",
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

when I try to import it the autocomplete would prefer to use the `my-library` as a package instead of the aliases, for example it would suggest:

```
import Image from "my-library/my-module-a/web/theme/Image"
import Image from "my-library/my-module-b/web/theme/Image"
import Image from "my-library/my-module-c/web/theme/Image"
```

But it will not suggest:

```
import Image from "theme/Image"
```

although that alias works perfectly fine.

Comment: So what are you actually suggesting in this answer?